# How can I get requests.get to run multiple times to download multiple files from one website?

Tags: python, python-requests

I feel like this should be very simple to do, but I'm not very experienced with python so i'm having trouble.  I'm using requests to download files from a website.  Each of their download urls are the same save for the release number:

http://maltinerecords.cs8.biz/release/**172**/MARU**172**.zip

I'm trying to write a script using requests to get the file from each url, from 1-172.  Thanks, and apologies for my inexperience.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
import requests

for num in range(1, 173):
    response = requests.get("http://maltinerecords.cs8.biz/release/**{0}**/MARU**{0}**.zip".format(num))
    with open("MARU**{0}**.zip".format(num), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i was looking for, works flawlessly

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.